# How to automate the process of using outputs from R as inputs in another software?

Tags: r, automation, rstudio

My programming skills are very limited and am a quite new user in R language. Currently I am doing some (non-statistical) data analyses in RStudio. The outputs from these analyses act as inputs to a microsimulation program VISSIM. Once I complete my analyses in RStudio, I manually enter a lot of values in VISSIM. 
Is there any possibility that I could automate this process i.e. the final values automatically get entered into VISSIM? If there is one, what should I learn for that? Please guide to a newbie. I am ready to learn anything new. This can save a lot of time.

Following is GUI of VISSIM. Different menus take different input options:
[image]

Comment: You can try AutoHotKey (http://www.autohotkey.com/)... But you need improve your programming skills before

Comment: Does VISSIM allow you to read in settings from a file? Do you physically have to type in the values at the keyboard? Does it have a graphical interface?

Comment: Rcoster, thanks for suggestion. @MrFlick As far as I know VISSIM does not read settings from an external file, I have to physically type values in VISSIM using keyboard. It does have a graphical interface. You can see PTV VISSIM website here: http://vision-traffic.ptvgroup.com/en-us/products/ptv-vissim/ if you like.

Comment: It seems the problem has little to do with R specifically. It's a question of whether you can import values from anywhere into VISSIM. I would contact their technical support to see what options are available to you.

Comment: That's a good idea. But just for my curiosity, what steps does one has to take to automate this kind of operation in programming? VISSIM uses Python language for overriding many default models so we have 2 languages here.

Comment: This blog should get you headed in the right direction: http://tgmstat.wordpress.com/2014/05/21/r-scripts/

Comment: In order to automate stuff you "typically" use programs that are amenable to automation by providing a application programming interface (API) or documented file format that you can generate dynamically. In R probably all you are going to do is write out parameter values to a flat text file. If VISSIM uses python, then you may be able to write python code to read that text file to create a model using those parameters. R can't magically make other programs do things they don't want to though.

Comment: VISSIM does have an API (as described in its manual). So that's what I need to learn!

Comment: Here is how: http://www.polymtl.ca/wikitransport/index.php?title=Traffic_micro-simulation_calibration_and_validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard method of sending data to VISSIM is through its COM interface.  The languages people typically use are MATLAB, C++, C#, Python, Java, and VBA.  In your documents folder you should have a PTV Vision folder.  Search it for a folder entitled 'Basic Commands' which contains a lot of sample code.